# Is this some kind of banana

Tags: identification, banana

[image: Single Flower perhaps banana plant]

Will this flower identify the plant? The plant had a single flower in July. The leaves are like a banana plant I think.

Comment: That is most certainly it. It seems it is widely grown in the UK but is a noxious weed in some countries.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be *Hedychium gardnerianum* or Kahili ginger, originally from the Himalayas. Here an example on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedychium_gardnerianum). It is not a banana, it is actually a member of the ginger family *Zingiberaceae*.

It is poisonous for grazing animals.